# MySQL, get data between start and end date columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've read a few similar questions then mine, where I could find queries that were pretty much the same I'm using. But I had to ask, because I would like to understand why this is not working:

I have the following data:

```
id  category_id     start_date  end_date    image   campaign_id     published
1   1               2011-07-05  2011-07-5   a.gif   3               1           
2   1               2011-07-01  2011-07-15  c.gif   3               1
3   37              2011-07-01  2011-07-04  d.gif   3               1
```

I expect to get rows 1 and 2, from this query:

```
SELECT id, category_id, start_date, end_date FROM categories_campaigns WHERE  start_date <= NOW() AND end_date >= NOW();
```

From what I've experienced, the only row returned is the second. Also this one, gives me the second,

```
SELECT category_id, start_date, end_date FROM categories_campaigns WHERE   end_date >= NOW();
```

The next one returns me all 3,

```
SELECT category_id, start_date, end_date FROM categories_campaigns WHERE   start_date <= NOW();
```

The datatype for both columns are DATE. So, my question is, how to solve this ? Why is this happening ? Or I've got an obvious error that I'm not finding on what to look for.

Comment: if it is solved post the solution as your own answer and accept that

Comment: What is the output from `SELECT NOW()`? Is it by any chance UTC time?

Comment: @Shakti Singh, ok then, i'll do that. Tks

Answer (score 2):

Working query

```
SELECT
    category_id, start_date, end_date
FROM
    categories_campaigns
WHERE
    start_date <= DATE(NOW()) and end_date >= DATE(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this:

```
SELECT category_id, start_date, end_date FROM categories_campaigns WHERE left(now(),10) between start_date and end_date;
```

Comment: Nice tip! I'll also try your approach in future. Easier to read for dates, I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `start_date` and `end_date` are of `date` datatype. But `NOW()` returns a date-**time** value.

Use `CUR_DATE()` instead of `NOW()`